# Omnet++ : Simulation terminated with exit code: 8b

Tags: omnet++

I want to simulate a network in omnet++; however, in Qtenv, while I click on "Run" to run the simulation it crashes with no error in code but it says:

> Simulation terminated with exit code: 8b

Does anyone know why this happens?

Actually, I was expecting no error!

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74357755/edit) your question and provide [mcve]? Moreover, to help you we need to know what OS are you using, what is the version of OMNeT++, what did you do before, what network do you use etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is the cause, you have to debug your simulation, because this is caused by an exception somewhere in your code.

The error code is in case of exceptions: `128+signal_number`.

0x8b is decimal 139, which means this is signal 11: segmentation violation.

Your code is wrong and you access an invalid pointer somewhere.